# Entering user and password in web generates error 462 remote server machine not found

Tags: excel, vba, authentication, web-scraping, passwords

I want to connect to a web page that asks for a username and password.

I need a macro that

- puts the user and password and press click to enter a first web page.
- navigates to a second page which has the data I need.

The code does not fill in the user and password and click. I get an error 462 remote server machine not found.

```
Sub ExtractActivo()

Dim IE As Object
Dim pagina1 As HTMLDocument
Dim pagina2 As HTMLDocument

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True

‘First page
IE.navigate "https://www.activobank.com/cs/Satellite/BC/"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
Set pagina1 = IE.document
pagina1.getElementById("userDNI").Value = Range("M1").Value
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
pagina1.getElementById("pinNif").Value = Range("M2").Value
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
pagina1.getElementsByClassName("btn tipo4")(0).Click
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))

‘Second page
IE.navigate "https://www.activobank.com/activobank/CUGlobalPositionNew.init.bs"

Set pagina2 = IE.document

'Here code to download tables

IE.Quit

Set IE = Nothing: Set pagina1 = Nothing: Set pagina2 = Nothing

End Sub
```

Html of second page

```
<!-- /1. Ahorro Inversión -->         
<!-- ELEMENTOS DEL BLOQUE -->
<table border="0" width="494" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="white" style="margin-bottom:10px">
<tr  class=apartado >
<td width="20" class="a12" height="10" align="right">
<a href='javascript:plegarDesplegar("1","CC");' >
<img id="_CC" src="/neti/images/AB/expandir.gif" border="0">
</a>
</td>
<td class="a12" width="354" height="15" valign="center" align="left"><b>&nbsp;Cuentas a la vista
</b>
</td>
<td width="120" height="15" valign="center" align="right">
<!-- MILLORA -->
<span class="a12b">999,99
&euro;
</span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<div id="_CC0" style="display:none">
<table border="0" width="494" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="white">
<!-- JV-18725 Añadimos CI -->
<tr class="fila1">
<!--  Boton edicion cuenta -->
<td class="a11" width="195" height="15" align="left" valign="top" nowrap>
<table class="septd2">
<tr>
<td style="padding-left:20px" valign="center" align="left" width="10">
<a href='javascript:mostrarEdicion("_CC0");' >
<img id="_BtEdicion__CC0" name="_BtEdicion" src="/neti/images/AB/Lapiz-11x11.png" border=0>
</a>
</td>
<td align="left" class="a11">
<div id="_CC0_CC">
CUENTA ACTIVA
</div>
<div id="_CC0_M" style="display:none;">
<span class="returnicon">
<script>
function validate_CC0(){
var valueInput = document.getElementById("_CC0_IN").value;
valueInput = valueInput.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\u002e\s\u002c\u003a\u003b\u003f\u0021\u002d\u005f\u00A1\u00BF\u002D\u00E4\u00E1\u00E0\u00E7\u00EB\u00E9\u00E8\u00ED\u00EC\u00EF\u00F1\u00F6\u00F3\u00F2\u00FA\u00F9\u00FC\u00C4\u00C1\u00C0\u00C7\u00CB\u00C9\u00C8\u00CD\u00CC\u00CF\u00D1\u00D3\u00D2\u00D6\u00DA\u00D9\u00DC\u00A1\u00BF]/g,"");
document.getElementById("_CC0_IN").value = valueInput;
document.getElementById("_CC0_CC").innerHTML = valueInput;
}
</script>
<input id="_CC0_IN" type="text" maxlength="25" onblur='validate_CC0();timeNameAccountAuto("/activobank/","_CC0_IN","xxxxx","CUENTA ACTIVA","2","La descripción debe contener como mínimo 3 caracteres","La descripción debe contener como máximo 25 caracteres");' onkeydown='return validateExit(event)' onKeyPress='validate_CC0();return validateKeyPress(event,"xxxxxxx","/activobank/","La descripción debe contener como mínimo 3 caracteres","2","CUENTA ACTIVA","La descripción debe contener como máximo 25 caracteres")'/>
<a href='javascript:getNameAccount("_CC0","xxxxx","/activobank/","CUENTA ACTIVA","2");' >
<img src="/neti/images/AB/Borrar-9x9.png" border=0 >
</a>
</span>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-left:20px" valign="center" align="left" width="10">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="a11" width="230" height="15" align="left" valign="center" colspan="2">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="alias_cc_2">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following targets the correct elements and clicks submit. It uses [] attribute = value css selectors and # id selector.

```
Option Explicit   
'VBE > Tools > References:
' Microsoft Internet Controls
Public Sub Login()
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.activobank.com/cs/Satellite/BC/"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        .document.querySelector("[name=userDNI]").Value = "abc"
        .document.querySelector("[name=pinDNI]").Value = "123"
        .document.querySelector("#button1").Click

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Stop

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Log in on the first page and then navigate to the second page.
Once I'm on the second page, what I need to do is copy the balance from my bank account from that page to Excel.
That balance is in a table that I would like to copy complete and, if it is not possible, at least copy the value 999.99 of the html code that I have added to my original question.
What should I add in the code to do it?

Comment: I suggest you consider accepting this answer and opening a new question with the next part and be sure to include the html as we cannot log in and view the page. You can use the snippet tool available via edit to add html. Don’t insert pictures of html.

Comment: Sorry, I will do.

Comment: Sorry, How can I accept your answer? I dont't know how to do that.

Comment: Ok. I did it. And the next question is in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55250830/copy-with-vba-to-excel-the-balance-of-my-current-account-from-a-web-page

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not clicking the right button. Going to the page you linked, and inspecting the login button does not show me an element of "btn typo4" but:

```
<input id="button1" name="accept" type="button" value="Entrar" onclick="return validate()" class="btn login" tabindex="3" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
```

Why do you try to locate the button by classname when he has an inputId ?

Bonus : https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/

xmlhttp request are better for web scraping with vba.

Feel free to remove if i'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your field/class names are from the 'Activo Online' tab, but the URL for your 'First Page defaults to the 'Particulares' tab. You probably either need to use the login fields on 'Particulares' or navigate to 'Activo Online' first.

https://www.activobank.com/cs/Satellite/BC/Activo-Online/1191355337777/es/ appears to be a direct link to the page that contains the fields you are trying to work with.

You also probably need a loop after each:

```
IE.navigate
```

to wait for the page to load. So add this code underneath:

```
Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
DoEvents
Loop
```

Which should mean you can then get rid of your 'application.wait' lines.